# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.Box

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

I have two JPanels leftTextField and rightTexTField which both contain one instance of FileBox as followed:

```
 public class FileBox extends Box {
    private Box content;

    public FileBox(String text) {
        super(3); // ?
        content = Box.createVerticalBox();
        init(text);     
    }

    private void init(String text) {
        JTextArea editor = new JTextArea();
        editor.setDragEnabled(true);            
        editor.setText(text);
        editor.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editor);

        content.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        content.add(scrollPane);
        content.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
    }

    public Box get() {
        return content;
    }

    public void set(Box content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

I also have two buttons with actionListeners and want to perform some Code, once the listeners gets triggered. I tried something like this:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource().equals(buttonToLeft)) {
            FileBox left = (FileBox) leftTextPanel.getComponent(0);
            FileBox right = (FileBox) rightTextPanel.getComponent(0);           

            left.set(right.get());
        }
}
```

However i do get the error Message as posted in the title which i don't understand. FileBox is a Component of my leftTextPanel, because i added it with leftTextPanel.add(new FileBox()) etc. Is there any reason why it is now an instance of Box and i cannot cast it? How do i solve this issue?

Comment: super(3); == e.g. super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);, another reason why don't use numbers constants

Comment: create a standard container, define LayoutManager inside contructor, don't extends part of methods for LayoutManager, more in Oracle tutorial how to use BoxLayout

Comment: @ mKorbel: Well my attempt of creating a standard container (cause i need that thing several times) is the FileBox class. Why should i define a LayoutManager in it's constructor? I will instances of it in a mainclass where i store those instances. So where exactly is my code not being ok here?

Comment: I don't know how to test it:-), who knows, I'm not my magics globe has hibernation

Comment: Confusingly, `FileBox` appears to both _extend_ `Box` and _contain_ a `Box`. What's the real [problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/163188).

Comment: Could you post the whole stacktrace?